# How to display(overlay) play button on image while post on Facebook

Tags: share, facebook-social-plugins

Question: How to display(overlay) play button on image while post on Facebook,

Scenario : i have one page with display one image on that page,
also i have facebook and twitter share button on this page,
now when i post this link on facebook or twiiter the image is display fine

the problem is i want to add '**play button**' on facebook, so once user click on the play button(overlay button on image) user redirect to original site..

please let me know better solution without creating new image or modified in existing image

Let me know if any questions..

Many Thanks
Chirag

Comment: Sites that do that probably use an image with a fake play button on it; they don't overlay the original, I don't think. But why would you want to mislead your users? If it doesn't play, don't add a play button.

Comment: Hi christian 
actually we have two option on our page
either image or video
if admin upload image then only image will display on fb post
but if admin upload video(video save on youtube we only save unique id in our db) then image with play button will display on facebook post

Thanks